# Swisscom Application Cloud: nodejs with java jdk

Tags: java, node.js, cloud-foundry, buildpack, swisscomdev

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs app to swisscom application cloud.
The app uses the [node-java module](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java).
While staging the app, I get an error message:

```
[node-java] Error: not found: javac
```

is it possible to deploy apps with multiple buildpacks (e.g. nodejs and java) like on heroku (besides creating a custom buildpack)?

@UPDATE:
I'm (now) aware of the (experimental) [multi-buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/multi-buildpack) for cloudfoundry. unfortunately it won't detect my app as java app (which isn't) and anyway, it would ony install the jre but not the jdk.
Is there a possibility (besides a docker image or custom buildpacks) to have jdk in the app container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because there seems no way to add custom packages to the cf base image (cflinuxfs2) provided by swisscom, I forked the official cloud foundry buildpack and let it install the openjdk-7-jdk package before doing all the nodejs related stuff (https://github.com/juckerf/nodejs-openjdk-buildpack)

(unfortunately the multi-buildpack with the [nodejs buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack) and [herokus apt buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) didn't work for me because the nodejs buildpack was executed before the apt buildpack, regardless of the order in the `multi-buildpack.yml`)